# Active Directory 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS) - LDAP: error code 50 - 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150A45

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I tried to set an attribute to another user while I was logged with my account, which is member of `Domain Admins` group of the Active Directory.

`Error while executing LDIF- [LDAP: error code 50 - 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150A45, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 50 - 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150A45, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0`

What I need to do in order to be able to edit data using LDAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the application and select Run as Administrator.

When you are a member of one of the special restricted groups such as Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, or Administrators, those group memberships are blocked from your normal process token.  To use these group memberships, you need to elevate by using Run as Administrator.

You can verify that the groups are blocked by running SysInternals' Process Explorer, right-click on the application, select Properties, and on the Security tab, the groups will have a Deny in the Flags column.

Comment: Your answer is not valid in my case, I'm running from Linux and conecting to LDAP so local process permission has nothing to do with that. Still, I solved the problem, I was connecting using a normal user instead of the admin one :p

Comment: @sorin - Well late, but there is nothing in your question, or in the tags, that would help other members know you were using Linux. Maybe this no longer happens in your questions, but if not, more details always help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are `Domain Admin` you should be able to do this. In my case I was connecting using another user.

Comment: You may want to update your question - you were not, in fact, acting as Domain admin.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the run as admin is still probably the root of the problem
eg this error will show when transferring fsmo roles if you don't authenticate
like this
sudo samba-tool fsmo transfer --role=all
vs authenticating properly
sudo samba-tool fsmo transfer --role=all -U some-schema-admin-user
so I would authenticate your command as a higher level user.